# SQL: Posso ter cláusulas no GroupBy que não aparecem no Select?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, group-by

Sei que não posso ter cláusulas no select que não apareçam no Group By. Mas e o contrário, é possível? Por exemplo:

```
Select B
From Table
Group By A,B
```

Answer (score 2):

Vou responder para os dois SGBDs nas tags da pergunta:

O Group By junta um conjunto de registos e produz um sumário (um único registo) para cada um dos grupos identificados. Os grupos são identificados com base numa ou mais colunas ou expressões incluídas na cláusula Group By.

Tanto o MySql como o Oracle permitem que a tua cláusula SELECT omita colunas incluidas no Group By. Por exemplo, esta instrução irá funcionar nos dois SGBDs.

```
SELECT coluna1, COUNT(1)
FROM tbl_tabela
GROUP BY coluna1, coluna2
```

(A utilidade de uma expressão como a anterior pode ser questionada, é claro. Visto que perdes informação essencial para identificar o grupo criado para cada uma das linhas no resultado.)

Para completar, e porque é o SGBD que estou a usar ultimamente, o Sql Server, de acordo com a informação no [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx), permite também que as expressões Group By contenham colunas das tabelas, tabelas derivadas, views da cláusula FROM. No entanto, as colunas do Group By não necessitam obrigatoriamente de aparecer na cláusula SELECT.

Um último comentário em relação à tua pergunta, o MySql **permite** que na tua cláusula SELECT incluas colunas que não estão no GROUP BY. Mais info na página do [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado! E quanto ao SQL padrão, isto também é possível?